# what hypothesis test to use for non-numeric data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, t-test

I have a question and I'm being asked to specify which test to use and then conduct it. However, the data given is non-numeric. the question statement is "males and females differ in whether or not they regularly eat breakfast" and the data given is like, ffffmmmfmmfm YYYNNYYNN. I was thinking paired t-test but I don't know what to work on! please help.

Comment: You can test this using a 2x2 contingency table.  Either the chi square or Fisher exact test test for differences between male and female groups.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: As other responses indicate, the data are perfectly numeric in essence: all that is needed is to count categories.

Answer (score 2):

My comment that the data can be put into a $2\times 2$ table and under appropriate assumptions apply Fisher's exact test is one way to achieve your goal. The chi-square test is another possibility but,  because the distribution of the test is asymptotic, this test requires that none of the cells has low expected cell counts.

Comment: The requirement for applying the chi-squared distribution is that there be *relatively few* cells with low *expected counts*.  It's perfectly fine to have many cells with low *observed* counts.

Comment: I accept your point and have edited my answer.